# How to get only device token from an array of multiple elements in objc?

Tags: ios, objective-c, rtf

I have an array like this (printed in console) :-

```
"DeviceToken\\uc0\\u82326E7A915B6A5CBC0E3EFF2F05F16018ED143F0EC437C12C7F83E8F8ADCCAD07E3\\u8232Created\\u82323\\'a0weeks,4\\'a0daysago\\u8232LastRegistration\\u82323\\'a0weeks,4\\'a0daysago\\u8232Status\\u8232Inactive\\u8232Alias\\u8232None\\u8232Tags\\u8232None\\u8232\\u8232\\",
"DeviceToken\\uc0\\u82320EF3D38E46243D726E7800B480AC971CDDD8D00A0FFC46029662BC6F3A629F24\\u8232Created\\u82321\\'a0monthago\\u8232LastRegistration\\u82322\\'a0days,8\\'a0hoursago\\u8232Status\\u8232Inactive\\u8232Alias\\u8232None\\u8232Tags\\u8232None\\u8232\\u8232\\",
```

and so on..

Actually this is conversion from rtf file to array. Now I want to display only device tokens from it, not the full information. How can I implement it ?

Comment: have you write any code for this ?

Comment: yes i have done the conversion from rtf to array. But know dont know how to move further to get only the device token values from it ?

Comment: please post some snippet from your code and let us know which information you want to remove from this array.....

Comment: Can you post which code you use to get this ?

Comment: NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"FileName" ofType:@"rtf"];
    NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSArray *array = [myText componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];



And my file includes this type of multiple information:-

Device Token  6E7A915B6A5CBC0E3EFF2F05F16018ED143F0EC123C12C7F83E8F8ADCCAD07E3  
Created 
 2 weeks, 4 days ago 
 Last Registration  
2 weeks, 4 days ago  
Status  
Inactive 
 Alias  
None  
Tags
  None

Comment: Here i am posting which finds capital laters from array hope it will work for you


NSArray *array = @[@"one", @"two", @"three"];
NSArray *capArray = [array valueForKeyPath:@"capitalizedString"];

hope it will helps you

Comment: Here which one device token from array?

Comment: Do you want  to get this one - u82326E7A915B6A5CBC0E3EFF2F05F16018ED143F0EC437C12C7F83E8F8ADCCAD07E3

Comment: But it is 69 character here

Answer (score 0):

iOSLearner I tried to get the token only from the array.I got the solution.

```
NSMutableArray *arrayToken = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"DeviceToken\\uc0\\u82326E7A915B6A5CBC0E3EFF2F05F16018ED143F0EC437C12C7F83E8F8ADCCAD07E3\\u8232Created\\u82323\\'a0weeks,4\\'a0daysago\\u8232LastRegistration\\u82323\\'a0weeks,4\\'a0daysago\\u8232Status\\u8232Inactive\\u8232Alias\\u8232None\\u8232Tags\\u8232None\\u8232\\u8232\\",@"DeviceToken\\uc0\\u82320EF3D38E46243D726E7800B480AC971CDDD8D00A0FFC46029662BC6F3A629F24\\u8232Created\\u82321\\'a0monthago\\u8232LastRegistration\\u82322\\'a0days,8\\'a0hoursago\\u8232Status\\u8232Inactive\\u8232Alias\\u8232None\\u8232Tags\\u8232None\\u8232\\u8232\\",nil];
NSLog(@"The arrayTokens are-%@",arrayToken);
NSMutableArray *arrayExactToken = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(int i=0;i<arrayToken.count;i++)
{
    NSString *strTokenObject = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayToken objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSLog(@"The token is - %@",strTokenObject);
    NSString *strNew = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[strTokenObject componentsSeparatedByString:@"\\"] objectAtIndex:2]];
    strNew = [strNew substringFromIndex:5];
    NSLog(@"The strNew is - %@",strNew);
    [arrayExactToken addObject:strNew];
}
NSLog(@"The tokens are - %@",arrayExactToken);
```

The printed results are

```
The tokens are - (
6E7A915B6A5CBC0E3EFF2F05F16018ED143F0EC437C12C7F83E8F8ADCCAD07E3,
0EF3D38E46243D726E7800B480AC971CDDD8D00A0FFC46029662BC6F3A629F24
)
```

Comment: I have 2500 records.. So (NSMutableArray *arrayToken = ........)
This can't be done.

Comment: For sample I just added the two device token.As you posted two objects of array I added two objects to array.Don't see the array token here.See the code in loop.Even If you give 2000 records the result is same that what I have done in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you have a file that you are bundling with your app and you are having problems parsing it at runtime.  Therefore the solution is to bundle the device IDs in a different file format and package that with your app (either instead of, or as well as, the `.rtf` file).

You can either do this during the build (if the input `.rtf` files changes frequently) or once manually (if it doesn't change frequently).

You have a fair amount of choice of the file format to use to store the device IDs in the app bundle:

- Text file (one line per device ID).
- Plist file (array of device IDs).
- sqlite file (table of devices IDs).

All these formats are easy to process at runtime.

So this is not a technical answer to your problem.  My answer is to avoid this problem in the first place and make life easy for yourself.